# Where did all that water go?

Tags: mission-impossible, mission-impossible-rogue-nation

In *Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation*, Ethan Hunt must switch access cards in an underwater chamber. There is a large intake with gallons upon gallons of water flowing down it constantly, but no mention of an outlet for all that water. The only exit seems to be a closed hatch. Where was all that water going?

Answer (score 1):

They were in a power station, and the water was flowing through a turbine.  If you recall, when the "flood gates" at the top were opened, the water began circulating and Hunt had to start swimming against that current.  The water would flow through the grate at the bottom of that chamber.

Comment: If there were a grate on the bottom, wouldn't all the water drain out when the water was shut off?

Comment: There **is** a grate on the bottom.  And it's probably on a different valve.  If they emptied it and let it drain, Hunt would have nothing to jump into.

Comment: But if they had control of that valve as well, why not open it once Ethan is in the chamber so he wouldn't have to hold his breath? There's no mention of it by anyone. It's just taken as a given that Ethan has to be underwater the whole time.

Comment: Well, that would be a plot hole.  ;o)  There's no way he's getting through the grate, and the hatch and location of the data card are about 20 feet off the "floor", but certainly he's athletic enough to climb to those positions if the chamber was empty.  So, to the best of my recollection there was no reason why they couldn't drain the chamber once he was in it.  I started dozing off at that point in the movie, perhaps they needed the water in the way they need water for nuclear fuel cells?  There was some large device in the center of the chamber that I didn't quite understand.